# Enabling HTTPS on EC2 Instance

Tags: ssl, certificate, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2

I have an elastic public IP for my EC2 instance. I have an Nginx server running on it (and nodejs as a backend server). I'd like to enable HTTPS access to my server.

My questions:

1. Can I create an SSL certificate (not self-signed) using just my elastic public IP?
2. If not, my department has a domain. let's say, **https://www.example.com**. This already points to a server with some IP. How can I enter the record (and where?) so that **https://www.example.com/base-route** points to my elastic public IP without affecting any existing routes? If this is possible, do I create SSL certificate for https://www.example.com or https://www.example.com/base-route
3. If I create a new SSL certificate for https://www.example.com/base-route, will it have any impact on the existing certificate for https://www.example.com/?

Answer (score 2):

SSL certificates are for verifying hosts. A host is identified by either a domain name (by DNS) or an IP address, so.

1. Yes, you can get a trusted SSL certificate for your IP address. As far as I'm aware of, Riven Cloud sells this for $9/yr which is the cheapest (I'm not affiliated!)
2. No. Certificates are for *hosts*, not for paths. You have two options here:

   - Ask your administrator to delegate a subdomain for you, like `base-route.example.com`, so you can acquire a certificate for that.
   - Ask your administrator to reverse-proxy the base route to your instance. They'll still handle the certificate issue, but you'll have control over the *content* of this base path.
3. As noted in point 2, there's no way you'd get a certificate for a path. You only set it up for a host (domain or IP address).

Comment: Thank you. Will Riven Cloud provide ssl certificate for elastic public IP of an EC2 instance?

Comment: @Sid They may. You'll have to check it out by yourself. In general, as long as it's a publicly reachable IP address, you should be able to obtain one after ownership verification.

Comment: you can get free certs from Lets Encrypt https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Clarify: LE provides certs only for DNS names, not IP addresses.

Comment: that is correct, you made it abundantly clear in your answer that certs are only for verifying hosts via a domain name